# How to remove the previous cuda 7.5 and install new version of v. 10 in centos 7?

Tags: centos-7, cuda

There is a process of the installation of cuda 10.0 [How to install NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit on CentOS 7 Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-on-centos-7-linux) where a repository is installed through, and then cuda can be installed by

```
rpm -i cuda-repo-rhel7-10.0.130-1.x86_64.rpm
yum install cuda
```

but installation fails because cuda 7.5 was already installed. Then I need to remove cuda 7.5 but I can't.
There is no /usr/local/cuda directory and cannot find uninstallation command and nvcc locates in /usr/bin. I do not remember how to install cuda 7.5 then how can I remove coda 7.5 and install cuda 10.0?

The error message for "yum install cuda" which I remember is

> Cuda 1:7.5... is already installed and it is the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check the installed package by

```
yum list installed
```

where I found

> cuda.x86_64         1:7.5.18-3.el7.nux         @nux-dextop

(I remember the package name is "cuda.x86_64") So I could remove cuda by

```
yum remove cuda.x86_64
```

When try to install cuda again, it will tried to install again coda 7.5..
So disable repo of nux-dextop by editing /etc/yum.repos.d/nux_dextop

> sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/nux_dextop
>
> [nux-dextop]
>
> enabled=0

Then I could install coda 10.0 through

```
yum install cuda
```